# Adding gmaps4jsf into spring jsf application using maven dependancies

Tags: spring, maven, google-maps, jsf

I am developing a JSF spring web-based application i want to use google maps in my application i want to add it using maven could any one help me adding this jar , i tried to add it and i have added the dependency and the repository for it bu i got this error : Missing artifact com.googlecode.gmaps4jsf:gmaps4jsf-core:jar:3.0.0

here in my pom.xml :

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>prime-repo</id>
        <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>

        <repository>
        <id>googlecode.com</id>
        <name>gmap Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://gmaps4jsf.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gmaps4jsf-repo</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>



</repositories>



  <dependencies>

<!-- map dependency  -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.gmaps4jsf</groupId>
    <artifactId>gmaps4jsf-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency> 
[..................]

</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem. For now the solution is download the jar and install is your local maven or in your private repository, for example nexus or artifactory.

Comment: Googlecode has been dead for several years now, so no wonder it does not work anymore ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Google code has been dead for several years now (it is [archived](https://code.google.com/archive/p/gmaps4jsf/)). By putting 'gmaps4jsf maven' into a searchengine, I found a repo in github

https://github.com/hazems/gmaps4jsf/tree/master/gmaps4jsf-repo